# Sabre API Request URI Authentication issue

Tags: sabre

I am not able to get the JSON Data for the below API Request. 
Getting Authentication problem.

https://api.test.sabre.com/v1/shop/flights?origin=JFK&destination=LAX&departuredate=2018-07-07&returndate=2018-07-09&onlineitinerariesonly=N&limit=10&offset=1&eticketsonly=N&sortby=totalfare&order=asc&sortby2=departuretime&order2=asc&pointofsalecountry=US

{"status":"NotProcessed","type":"Validation","errorCode":"ERR.2SG.SEC.MISSING_CREDENTIALS","timeStamp":"2018-04-10T12:11:35.221-05:00","message":"Authentication data is missing"}

Comment: Can you reply ASAP. thanks in advance

Comment: From the Sabre test site: https://developer.sabre.com/io-docs  "Please note that you first need to sign in before testing our APIs".

Comment: i have signed in and got the token key and authorization heder etc. In post man i am getting the response.  when i try to hit the url in browser it is not bring the JSON object. https://api.test.sabre.com/v1/shop/flights?origin=JFK&destination=LAX&departuredate=2018-07-07&returndate=2018-07-09&onlineitinerariesonly=N&limit=10&offset=1&eticketsonly=N&sortby=totalfare&order=asc&sortby2=departuretime&order2=asc&pointofsalecountry=US

Comment: So it works in Postman but it doesn't work in a browser? Sounds about right if you are not passing the token header in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to manipulate your headers to contain the credentials on your request with a plugin like tampermonkey for chrome